# VMWARE Host to Host Nic connection without switch

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

Dumb question.  If I had a free 10gb port on two vmware hosts, is it possible connect them directly without a physical switch in between them ?  Thanks

Would like to have a faster dedicated connection for Vmotion.

[image]

Comment: Sure. Why not?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to connect two servers directly using a crossover cable.
Configure both the servers interfaces on the same subnet. Try to ping from the host operating system. If it works then you have to map the physical interface with the virtual interface.

Comment: Automatic MDI/MDI-X is required part of Ethernet standard since 1Gbps, you don't even need a cross-over cable